# Jump List for Explorer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, jumplist

After an upgrade to Windows 10, I noticed that all entries (folders) in my Jump List for File Explorer do not open when I left-click on them.

The rest of my Jump Lists work as I would expect, with the left-click behavior opening the file or item or taking another default action. But for some reason, the Folders in File Explorer do nothing when I click on them (the Jump List actually closes).

When I right-click on the folder, there is an "Open" entry in the context menu, but it exhibits the same behavior (nothing but the Jump List closing). The presence of this entry at least tells me that Microsoft intends for the Open item to work.

How do I restore the behavior of a single-click opening of my File Explorer Jump List items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the suggestion of [a post](http://www.windows10forums.com/threads/file-explorer-jump-list-on-taskbar.823/#post-11647) [in a topic](http://www.windows10forums.com/threads/file-explorer-jump-list-on-taskbar.823/) about this very question, I looked into the hooks that the program WinCDEmu placed in my system.

I found that removing the Context Menu Handler (via the Registry) for WinCDEmu allowed the click on the item in the Jump List to open the item successfully.

I didn't test for files, since I only use folders in the Jump List, but the following Registry script will remove the WinCDEmu handler from the Context Menu:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\WinCDEmu]
```

If you ever wanted to restore the Context Menu Handler, you would use this Registry script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\WinCDEmu]
@="{A9901FCD-B4DF-43A1-BD5D-6C9F88679497}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. The jump list for the taskbar Windows Explorer icon showed it's list of items, but clicking on them had no effect. If I then right-clicked on an item I could open it with the ensuing Open option, and that worked, but it wasn't the best behavior.

I followed the above answer, but since I didn't have WinCDEmu installed I figured it must be another program. So I backed up the "ContextMenuHandlers" key and started deleting the key for each of the other programs listed there. In my case the culprit was the ExpressZip key. After deleting it, jump list was back to normal.

Strangely, Express Zip stills shows up in the Explorer context menu, so go figure.

Comment: I would guess that ExpressZip still shows up because there is an entry under `HKCR\Directory\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers`