# Windows 10 File Explorer cannot open pinned items

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar

I have File Explorer pinned to the task bar on my Windows 10 (1607) system. I never previously had issues, however now I cannot launch a pinned folder, any of them. Clicking on a pinned item does nothingness, very annoying.

A Google search kept turning on various references to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/996703/jump-list-for-explorer-in-windows-10) article, which says that the program WinCDemu disabled Jump List functionality. This answer does not work for me, as I never heard of this program nor do I have that installed. As such, the problem lies elsewhere.

The only thing that happened recently is my upgrade to Windows 10 Pro x64 1607 anniversary edition. I do not remember if it worked since then or not.

I did try rebooting the system, same thing.

By the way, my issue is different from the Start Menu Jump List functionality that I read about with respect to my search. I am not talking about the Start Menu File Explorer Jump List and the needing of creation of the `EnableXamlJumpView` registry entry, but rather the plain old fashioned right click on File Explorer pinned on my task bar and then clicking on a pinned directory. Yes, I tried unpinning a folder and then pinning that folder again (drag folder to File Explorer to pin). That did not resolve the issue.

Other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I decided to not delete this question in hopes that it might help someone else. My problem was in a software that is not readily obvious that it does anything with File Explorer.

I found my answer thinking on the WinCEemu answer and thought what shell "extension" that I might have installed and realized that I did install a software package recently, Movavi (movavi.com) Video Converter. I realized that the product mentioned that it created a shell extension. I thought nothing of it at the time.

Unlike WinCDemu and the other shell extension mentioned on another article (sorry I would have to find that again), I did have to reboot my system. Possibly logging out and back in would have done the trick, but I restarted my computer. Either way, simply uninstalling the product did not work.